# Count full string or subset of string in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse some text using regex and would like a combination of strings to only register as one match if the combination appears, but for any substring to be captured if only that substring appears. For example, I want either `foo bar` or either individual string, such that I get:

```
text = 'foo bar bar foo'
In: re.findall(some_pattern, text)
Out: ['foo bar', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Using `some_pattern = re.compile(r'foo|bar)` returns `['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo']`. But I can't begin to think of any other patterns that would make this work. How can I capture this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple `|`s:

```
import re
print(re.findall('foo bar|foo|bar', 'foo bar bar foo'))
```

Output:

```
['foo bar', 'bar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it: `foo(?: bar)?|bar`

Answer (score 1):

Could be used like this as well-

`import re
print(re.findall('((foo)\s?(bar))', 'foo bar bar foo'))`

Output:

`['foo bar', 'bar', 'foo']`